# Bst tree delete() method doesnt work

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am currently implementing a Binary Search Tree and I am wondering, why my delete() method doesn't work...
My findMin() method does work, I have tested it out so far.
I type in a key, which doesn't exist in the three and I get the right exception, but whenever I type in a key, which is existing, it just doesn't remove the node from the three...
So here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Bst {

Node root;
Node head;
Node tail;


public Bst(){
    root = null;
}

public void insert (Node root, int key){
    Node newNode=new Node(key);

    if(root==null){
        root=newNode;
    }

    if(key<=root.getKey()){
        if (root.getLeft()!=null){
            insert(root.getLeft(), key);
        }
        else{
            root.setLeft(newNode);
        }
    }

    if (key>=root.getKey()){
        if (root.getRight()!=null){
            insert(root.getRight(),key);
        }

        else{
            root.setRight(newNode);
        }

    }


    }

public void printTree(Node root){
    if (root==null) return;
    printTree(root.getLeft());
    System.out.print(root.getKey() + " ");
    printTree(root.getRight());
}

public Node treeToCDLL(Node root){
    if (root == null){
        return null;
    }

    Node leftTree=treeToCDLL(root.getLeft());
    Node rightTree=treeToCDLL(root.getRight());


    if (leftTree == null){
        head=root;
    }

    else {
        head=leftTree;
        leftTree.getLeft().setRight(root);
        root.setLeft(leftTree.getLeft());
    }

    if (rightTree==null){
        head.setLeft(root);
        root.setRight(head);
        tail=root;
    }

    else{
        tail=rightTree.getLeft();
        head.setLeft(tail);
        tail.setRight(head);
        root.setRight(rightTree);
        rightTree.setLeft(root);
    }

    return head;
}

public boolean find(Node root, int key){
    Node current=root;

    while(current!=null){

        if(current.getKey()==key){
            return true;
        }
        else if(current.getKey()>key){
            current=current.getLeft();
        }

        else
            current=current.getRight();
        }
    return false;
}

public void printList(Node head){
    Node current = head;

    while(current!=null){
        System.out.print(current.getKey() + " ");
        current=current.getRight();
        if(current==head) break;
    }
}

public Node findMin(Node root){
    Node current=root;
    if(root==null) return null;
    else{
    if(current.getLeft()!=null){
        return findMin(current.getLeft());
    }
    }
    return current;

}

public void delete(Node root, int key){
    Node current=root;

    if(root==null){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("baum ist leer");
    }

    else{
        if(current.getKey()>key){
            delete(current.getLeft(), key);
        }

        else if(current.getKey()<key){
            delete(current.getRight(),key);
        }

        else{
            if(current.getLeft()==null && root.getRight()==null){
                current=null;
            }

            else if(current.getLeft()==null){
                Node tmp=current;
                current=current.getRight();
                tmp=null;
            }

            else if(current.getRight()==null){
                Node tmp=current;
                current=current.getLeft();
                tmp=null;
            }

            else {
                Node min=findMin(current.getRight());
                Node tmp=current;
                current=min;
                tmp=null;

            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main (String[]args){

    Bst bst=new Bst();

    Node root=new Node(4);
    bst.insert(root, 2);
    bst.insert(root, 10);
    bst.insert(root, 3);
    bst.insert(root, 5);
    bst.insert(root, 6);
    bst.insert(root, 0);

    bst.delete(root, 2);

    System.out.print("in-order traversal: ");
    bst.printTree(root);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Der gesuchte Knoten : " + bst.find(root,7));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("der kleinste Knoten : " + bst.findMin(root));
    System.out.println();



    System.out.print("circular doubly linked list: ");
    Node head= bst.treeToCDLL(root);
    bst.printList(head);







}

}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node {

    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private int key;

    public Node(int key){
        this.key=key;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node left){
        this.left=left;
    }

    public Node getLeft(){
        return left;
    }

    public void setRight(Node right){
        this.right=right;
    }

    public Node getRight(){
        return right;
    }

    public int getKey(){
        return key;
    }

}
```

I would be glad if someone could help me...
I tried out to find a solution the whole day, but it seems like I won't find it on my own

Comment: Did you try to setup breakpoints and debug to see what's going on?

Comment: you didn't include your node class

Comment: hey, I have now posted my Node class as an answer, sry for that...
it seems like it is at lest recognizing the right key, since otherwise it wouldnt send me the exception, when I typed in a key, which doesn't exist, I just can't simply get rid away from that node...

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your program.  Have you tested your insert method?  It's not working the way you think.  I just stepped through it.  After all of the inserts you do your BST object is basically empty

Comment: hey, why? I mean it is giving me the right InOrder and also transforming it into a list and I can also find the minValue and any other key...
now I am really scared... would be happy, if you could tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Are you using an IDE for your program?

Comment: no I am really desperate, since I spent my whole day and also change my whole methode a lot of times but it is like always the same... whenever I type in a node, which is existing, programm runs without exceptions, but does not remove. whenever I type in somethin which does not exist in the three, then I get an exception.
I do not want to believe that my whole class is wrong, since I can insert nodes and find the minimum, can traverse and also make a linkedlist from it... hope you can explain me a bit exactlier, what you meant by no objects created

Answer (score 0):

Here, by doing this current=min you are not changing node in tree, but simply replacing a local pointer (current).
Either rewrite values of this node by setters, of get update getLeft on parent of the node.

```
 else {
     Node min=findMin(current.getRight());
     Node tmp=current;
     current=min;
     tmp=null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last else part of the `delete()` method, you are just simply assigning `null` values that doesn't mean the references would point to the `null` value.

e.g When the matched node is a leaf node, you are simply assigning `null` value to the `current` variable. You should assign `null`value to the `left`/`right` of `current`'s parent. Assuming `parent` is the parent node of `current` node.

```
 if(current.getLeft()==null && root.getRight()==null){
            if(current == parent.getLeft()) {
                 parent.left=null;
            } else {
                 parent.right == null;
            }
  }
```

These is same problem with other subsequent `else` blocks.

```
        else if(current.getLeft()==null){
            if(current == parent.left) {
                 parent.left= current.getRight();
            } else {
                 parent.right = current.getRight();
            }
        }

        else if(current.getRight()==null){
            if(current == parent.left) {
                 parent.left= current.getLeft();
            } else {
                 parent.right = current.getLeft();
            }
        }
```

You need to keep track of the parent node while traversing the tree.